# Событие клика на стандартную организацию (объект), уже отмеченную на карте

Tags: json, api, yandex-maps-api

API Яндекс.Карт реализован собственный механизм работы с событиями.

myMap.events.add('click', function () { alert('Событие на карте'); // Возникнет при щелчке на карте, но не на маркере. });

А как поймать событие клика на отметку на карте об организации, школе или остановке?

Comment: Зачем вы хотите поймать событие клика по организации, школе или остановке? Что вы собираетесь сделать? Ответ на этот вопрос поможет мне ответить на ваш.

Comment: я использую карту, встраивая ее в приложение 1С предприятие. По клику выполняется обратное геокодирование и поиск по организациям по найденному адресу. Когда пользователь кликает уже по отмеченной организации - ничего не происходит. Поиск по организациям иногда не выдает отмеченную организацию, и данные по этой организации не получается перехватить.

Comment: Можно посмотреть, где вы это используете? Является ли использование нарушением ПС https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/terms/index-docpage?from=mapsapi ?